# Broken content control in Word document

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins, word-contentcontrol, word-web-addins

In my office js app for Word, sometimes a content control looses connection, so I cannot see the content control any longer, and then the document is broken for inserting new content controls of that type. I am not able to delete the broken content control, and I am not able to insert text into the broken content control. The broken content control is not visible in the document, but it exists, since it is not a null object.

Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Is it possible to do anything at all after a content control has been broken? Is it possible to remove it in some manual way? Or remove the entire list of a certain type of content control?

Here is a long example explaining what happens after a broken content control:

```
const example = context.document.contentControls
  .getByTag("example")
  .getFirstOrNullObject();
context.sync();

if (!example.isNullObject) {
  console.log("Example: ", example);
  // This logs meaning that the first object with tag "example" is not a null object, 
  // so it exists somehow. 
  // Logs: "Example: n {m_contextBase: n, m_objectPath: t, m_context: n, _IsTracked: true}"

  example.insertHtml("Example text in existing content control", Word.InsertLocation.replace);
  context.sync();
  // This breaks and the rest of the code does not continue. 
  // But, if I remove this, and we continue anyways this happens: 

  example.delete(false);
  context.sync();
  console.log("Deleted"); // This is not logged meaning that it breaks on deleting the content control
}

 // What if I insert a new content control of the same type?
 const range = context.document.getSelection();
 const contentControl = range.insertContentControl();
 contentControl.title = "Example";
 contentControl.tag = "example;
 contentControl.appearance = Word.ContentControlAppearance.boundingBox;
 contentControl.insertHtml("Example in new content control", Word.InsertLocation.replace);
 contentControl.color = "lightSkyBlue";
 await context.sync();
     
 const html = contentControl.getHtml();
 await context.sync();
 console.log("html", html.value); // This is logged with the correct value
```

Comment: It seems it is specific to insertHtml. It seems that this sometimes breaks the content controls. When using insertText I am not getting this issue. But it would be much easier if I could insert using Html rather than text.

Comment: This looks like a bug. If you haven't gotten an answer here in a few days, try creating an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo.